# open document with alternate form from a link

Tags: lotus-domino

Similar to the functionality of using a form formula in a view, I would like to figure a way to provide someone with a link to a document via a URL and have it open in an alternate form.   I'm trying not to modify the actual form value on the document, that gets messy to keep straight.

The form is a very complicated form with tabbed tables and 90% admin data, but I would like to turn over the maintenance of just one small set of fields to the user community without them seeing everything else.

Is there a way to force a link to open it BY WAY OF A VIEW that has a form formula?   That is what I am thinking.   Either that or I create/populate some smallish document when providing the link, then send them a link to this smaller document and have it update the 'parent' in it's webquerysave event.

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: And you want to open it in Notes, using a notes:// url, or in a browser?

Comment: @D.Bugger...thanks, I'm embarrassed...I know that not sure why I didn't catch that myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember having a conversation about this with one of the original developers of the Domino web server many, many years ago -- but I wasn't 100% certain that I remembered the answer correctly. So, I just searched through my old documents looking for a draft of the article I was writing when I had that conversation (in 1997!). It turns out that I didn't cover it in that particular article, but I did cover it several years later in one of the chapters that I wrote for the Lotus Notes & Domino 6 Programming Bible

> You may be wondering why, since a UNID uniquely identifies any note, is it necessary to include both a Document UNID and a View UNID in a URL.  The same question actually applies to doclinks, which were discussed above.  The truth is that you don’t have to include a View UNID in either case, but it does serve a purpose if you do.  You can replace the View UNID in a URL with a zero, retaining the slash characters that surround it.  If you do this, Domino will not be able to execute a Form formula, which you may have included in the code of one or more Views in your application.  See chapter 15 for more information about Form formulas.

In other words, if you include the UNID of a view that has the Form Formula that you wnat in the `?OpenDocument` URL that you are sending to the server. The Form Formula will be respected.

Comment: I will try that and reply

Comment: Richard, thank you for the effort to give me a solution.   I tried replacing the view name in the URL with the unique id of the view, and it still did not work...opened with the default form of the database.  - Matt

Comment: Richard,  your tip was the one that helped me get there!    I have a suite of databases, and am pointing to one database that had not gotten the form yet that I need to open.    It just dawned on me so I updated that and tried again....this is awesome!  Thank you very much.   I have to use script on webqueryopen to populate a hidden field with the view unid, as I cannot figure out how in formula language to do it.   The link is built using formula language, so I will be able to pull that info and build the correct unid...I have it hard coded at the moment.  Thank you again for your help!

Comment: Glad to help. And nice to know that some of that mass of stuff rattling around in my ancient memory is still accessible and occasionally useful. :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to open the document in Notes, you could try to send them a notes-URL, in the form of

```
notes://yourServer/yourDatabase.nsf/yourView/yourKey?OpenDocument
```

Comment: Bravo, Dharman!!

Comment: This is trying to open in a browser, not Notes, but anyway, I tried this: https://www.example.com/dev/dbname.nsf/altFormView/81F8192A4BA59ECA8525828F000DFF93?EditDocument, which points to a specific doc.   At first I got "Special database object cannot be located".  I did not have any form set as a default form, so changed that.   Now that error is gone, but instead, despite the form formula in the view the URL is looking at, the document opens with my default form.   Seems like the form formula only works if you open directly from the view, not using a URL

Comment: NOTE:  the url above has been truncated here as I look at it.   The part after the view name is the unique ID of the correct document then "?EditDocument"

Comment: Could you maybe try as I suggested, with a sorted view and a key?